# how can I temporarily save a binary (file upload), is it possible to persist it to a json or localstorage?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm something new on the subject, excuse my ignorance. I am using `IONIC`, and in a moment I have to take a picture with my cell phone, then I have to save this photo. At the end of several screens and processes, I must upload my `data` to a post service including that `image`.

how can I persist that image in my application? I don't think it is possible to save a binary in the local storage of the cell phone, can I temporarily save it to a json and then send it as a `formData`?

Answer (score 0):

Save the File object by angular service or global variable until your post service;
or
Upload pictures when you select them and save the filePath return by server; do your post service